# How to fix a stray vertical line in the Atom window

Tags: atom-editor

There’s a white line in the left of the screen, also in all text boxes. This line is really annoying and I don’t know how to delete or hide it. Here’s a screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this a programming question?  Or is it just a question about how to use a tool (a text editor)?

Comment: Found a bunch of answers on a quick search: https://www.google.com/search?q=atom+editor+vertical+line

Comment: Hmm, it's not the wrap guide cause that's on the right. It looks like a bug. Have you tried simply closing and reopening Atom? Otherwise, have you customized the theme at all? Have you installed any packages recently?

Comment: Yes, I installed some packages recently, but I disabled all of them and nothing happened. I searched on google and got a lot of answers, but all of them referring to the wrap guide.

Comment: You haven't told us enough to help you. _WHICH_ packages did you install? Add that to your question without any "edit" or "update" tags. Write down the names if you want to keep them, then uninstall them and restart Atom. If the problem has disappeared and you want to reinstall any of the packages, or, you don't really want them but you're really interested in the problem child, then add them in one at a time, and see which one caused it to happen again. When you make mass changes to code or an application it's harder to see what broke something, so make small changes.

Comment: I did as The Tin Man suggested and it worked. The issue was caused by a package called 'python-suite'. Thank you all.